# Android get data using regexp

Tags: android

I have a html string in in which i am trying to get string between the tag using regexp and finally saving the value to array-list . But i am not able to get the string between the tag so my array-list is always empty.

```
  <span><div style=\'float:left; width:350px;\'>Pharmacie DAR D\'BAGH</div>
```

my code to get the data using regexp is

```
   private void findTextByRegExp()
     {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>dataList1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

          String pattern3 = "<span><div style=\'float:left; width:350px;\'>";
          String pattern4 = "</div>";
          String text = readFromFile();

         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern3) + "(.*?)" +   
            Pattern.quote(pattern4));
          Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
         while (m.find()) {

             ArrayList<String>dataAdd = new ArrayList<String>();
             dataAdd.add(m.group(1));
             dataList1.add(dataAdd);
             Log.d("Group data", "" + m.group(1));

          }
          Log.d("MY ARRAY LIST OD DATA", "" + dataList1);
      }
```

please help me how to achieve this using regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
String pattern3 = "<span><div style=\\'float:left; width:350px;\\'>";
```